# Suboptimal for loop on large-ish dataset

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have a `DataFrame` with several thousand rows containing artificial forex trading data. The first ten rows look like this:

[image]

I want to iterate over this set, and for each row, calculate the `CommonCurrency` which in this case would be USD. So for each row, I go over the `CurrencyPair`, `DeskRate` and `OrderQty` columns and calculate a `CommonCurrency`:

```
for i in range(len(order_data)):
    if (order_data['CurrencyPair'][i] == 'GBP/USD'):
        order_data['CommonCurrency'][i] = order_data['DeskRate'][i] * 
        order_data['OrderQty'][i] 
    elif (order_data['CurrencyPair'][i] == 'AUD/USD'):
        order_data['CommonCurrency'][i] = order_data['DeskRate'][i] * 
        order_data['OrderQty'][i]
    elif (order_data['CurrencyPair'][i] == 'EUR/USD'):
        order_data['CommonCurrency'][i] = order_data['DeskRate'][i] * 
        order_data['OrderQty'][i]
    elif (order_data['CurrencyPair'][i] == 'USD/CHF'):
        order_data['CommonCurrency'][i] = order_data['DeskRate'][i] / 
        order_data['OrderQty'][i]
    elif (order_data['CurrencyPair'][i] == 'EUR/GBP'):
        order_data['CommonCurrency'][i] = #different calculation
```

This does not seem like the right way of doing it, especially not if there's a large number of different currency pairs. Another problem I come across is when I get to `EUR/GBP`, because now I have to get both the `DeskRate` from `GBP/USD` and `EUR/USD`, which I can't see how I can do with this method.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One interesting feature in pandas is the concept of [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). There are even more pythonic ways of doing this, but using `loc`, you can assign values to a section of the dataframe using series (columns):

```
order_data.loc[order_data['CurrencyPair'].isin(('GBP/USD', 'AUD/USD', 'EUR/USD')), 'CurrencyPair'] = order_data['DeskRate'] * order_data['OrderQty']
order_data.loc[order_data['CurrencyPair'] == 'USD/CHF', 'CurrencyPair'] = order_data['DeskRate'] / order_data['OrderQty']
order_data.loc[order_data['CurrencyPair'] == 'EUR/GBP', 'CurrencyPair'] = some_func(order_data['DeskRate'], order_data['OrderQty'])
```

Thus avoiding any `for` loops